# Is there a way to represent a clear connection between an EC2 and RDS instance using the AWS-SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am currently working on an AWS visualization project that is supposed to visualize EC2 and RDS instances connecting to each other within a VPC. I currently use the AWS Javascript SDK to query information about my current EC2's and RDS Instances. I was wondering if anyone has suggestions for describing the edges between an EC2 and RDS?

Currently, we kind of have a solution that is using the inbounds and outbounds of the security groups for each instance. However, from my understanding, that would probably require each individual instance to have its own security groups.

In the end, we expect to have some sort of JSON object representing all EC2 instances, all RDS instances, and a list of edges connecting things to populate a graph (we are using cytoscape if that helps at all). Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you really want to understand the traffic in your VPC, use VPC Flow Logs (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html). Security Group configuration may be a reasonable proxy for that.